# How to update the value of other duplicate objects in array of object, if one of the duplicate item is updated

Tags: javascript

From below object I have concatenated all "roles" key value:

```
{
    "office1": {
        "roles": [
            {
                "name": "Test 0",
                "email": "test0@test.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 1",
                "email": "test1@test.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 2",
                "email": "test2@test.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 3",
                "email": "test3@test.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "office2": {
        "roles": [
            {
                "name": "Test 3",
                "email": "test3@test.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 4",
                "email": "test4@test.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test 5",
                "email": "test5@test.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so new concatenated array "combinedRoles" look like below, which have duplicate values (e.g. {"name": "Test 3", "email": "test3@test.com"}. I want to update all other duplicate objects in the array, if any one of the object is updated out of all duplicate objects. In below example array element 3 and 4 have similar value, so if I update the element 3 it should update element 4 as well or vice versa.

```
combinedRoles = [
    {
        'name': 'Test 0',
        'email': 'test0@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 1',
        'email': 'test1@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 2',
        'email': 'test2@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 3',
        'email': 'test3@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 3',
        'email': 'test3@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 4',
        'email': 'test4@test.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Test 5',
        'email': 'test5@test.com'
    }
]
```

Comment: You have to do it manually using javascript code..

Comment: build new array of linked list, so each element of array would point to head of linked list. You should write function which will find the index by given key, and then go through that index linked list element till end and update proper attributes of object

Comment: I've removed the `angular` and `angularjs` tags because they don't have any relevance to the question, but in the future, please keep in mind that those are two completely different frameworks, and you should only ever use one of the two tags (the version of the framework you're actually using) unless you're specifically asking about a difference between the two.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - I am using this piece of code in Angular JS application.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects that need to be updated together are always *exactly* the same, creating an array of references rather than using object literals might work.

```
const obj0 = {'name': 'Test 0',
    'email': 'test0@test.com'
}
const obj1 = {'name': 'Test 1',
    'email': 'test1@test.com'
}
const obj2 = {'name': 'Test 2',
    'email': 'test2@test.com'
}
const obj3 = {'name': 'Test 3',
    'email': 'test3@test.com'
}

obj = [obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj3]
```

Now obj[3] and obj[4] are two references to the same object, so anything you do to it will affect both references in the array:

```
obj[3].email = "foo"
console.log(obj[4].email) // "foo"
```

If the objects **aren't** always the same, then you could write a function to loop through the array, find every matching object, and update them manually, but that would depend on how you define two matching objects.

Comment: Array of object which is shown as an example is created from two different different object. So array elements 0-3 is coming from one object and element 4 is coming from another object. In UI I am using Underscore uniq function to show only unique values. And all the key of object is bind to editable text field., so while saving I want to update the other duplicate items, if any one of them is updated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you edit your question with an example that looks more like your actual use case?